# uitableviewCell must long press

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

As the question states, I put several `UITableView`-Elements on a `ScrollView`, so I can swipe and see different `UITableView`s with different content. The weird thing is that when I tap the `UITableViewCell`, it can't respond. But when I long press the `UITableViewCell` it works.
I also added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the `ScrollView`, maybe this is the reason, but I don't know why.

#### I add several HRDropDown object on my _bgScrollView

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @class HRDropDownView;
 @protocol HRDropDownViewDelegate <NSObject>

 @optional
 - (void) HRDropDownView:(HRDropDownView *)dropDown didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row;
 -(CGFloat) HRDropDownView:(HRDropDownView*)dropDown heightForRow:(NSInteger)row;
 -(NSInteger) numberOfRows:(HRDropDownView*)dropDown;
 -(UIView *) HRDropDownView:(HRDropDownView *)dropDown viewForRow:(NSInteger)row;
 @end

 @interface HRDropDownView : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

 @property (nonatomic, assign) id <HRDropDownViewDelegate> delegate;
 @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL isHidden;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger selectedRow;

 -(void)hide;
 - (void)showWithHeight:(CGFloat)height;
 -(void) reloadData;
 @end
```

#### like this

```
 _venderListView = [[HRDropDownView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(_venderTextField.frame)+ 1, CGRectGetMaxY(_venderBgView.frame)  , CGRectGetWidth(_venderBgView.frame) - 2, 0)];
 _venderListView.delegate = self;
 _venderListView.backgroundColor = kWhiteColor;
 [self.bgScrollView addSubview:_venderListView];
```

#### after that I add a TapGesture like this

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resignOnTap:)];
 [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
 [singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
 [self.bgScrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

#### and the resignOnTap: method looks like:

```
 - (void)resignOnTap:(id)iSender {
 [self.currentResponder resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: I tried the same thing having UITableView instances inside a UIScrollView. Its tappable.. meaning its responding to touches. I am not understanding why its not working.. Probably plz post your piece of code.

Comment: @Sivannarayana ,I have posted some code, thanks for your attention.